# Visual studio 2015 not removing pending changes immediately after a check-in (TFS 2015)

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015, synchronization

When my team and I were on visual studio 2013, after successfully checking in our pending changes, the files that were checked in would be removed from the pending changes window.

Ever since upgrading to 2015, we have lost this functionallity. Now, after a successfuly check in, the pending changes will remain in the pending changes window until they are manually undone or and identical check in is undertaken in which case all of the files will sync themselves with source control and will no longer be pending changes.

When diffing the files with their counterparts in source control after a successful check in, it is clear that there are no changes between the two despite the fact they are still in the pending changes window. Is it possible that we have overlooked a simple setting that allows us to sync with TFS immediatelyafter a check in?

Thanks

Comment: Are the pending changes under Included Changes or Excluded Changes?

Comment: All in the included window, its an odd issue ive not come across before. As far as I can tell, the local machine does not realise that the files have successfully been checked in (we use gated check in) and will still list the files as pending changes after a successful check in, despite them being identical to whats now on the server (diffing them shows no difference between local and source control).

Answer (score 0):

Never seen your issue before. Try to upgrade your TFS and VS to the latest edition.

Also, if the pending changes are under Excluded Changes, they won't be checked in.

- https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/develop-code-manage-pending-changes#work-with-automatically-detected-changes
- https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/check-your-work-team-codebase#include_exclude

Comment: Thanks for the advice, after some frustrating hours, it appears that our visual studio 2013 was reconciling after check in using a build notification pop up however 2015 is not. We can still manually reconcile however I am currently looking for a way to automatically reconcile after a check in.

Comment: @Alex23 Did you ever find a solution for this? I'm seeing this as well on a project we just changed from CI to gated check ins. I am running VS2015 Update 1 (updating to Update 3 as we speak), but I noticed the issue on a coworker's machine as well, and he is running Update 3.

Comment: Update -- Happens on VS2015 Update 3 as well. Spoke with another team that has been doing gated check-ins for a while. They see it on every project, and they just deal with clicking the Reconcile button after each build.